# Java Editing PDFs

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is there a way to draw lines on a graph for an existing PDF?  I have a custom graph that I need to plot the lines for and I wanted to see if there was anyway to do it with itext or any other open source PDF software.  Thank you for your consideration of this matter.

Comment: can you please detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: and why do you need it to be in PDF ?

Comment: With itext use a PdfStamper, get the over-content of the page in question, and use the line drawing methods of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a look at the [StampText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=117) example. It shows you how to create a `PdfStamper` and how to obtain a `PdfContentByte` object. In this example, we stamp text on the existing PDF.

You want to draw lines, which also requires a `PdfContentByte` because that class has an abundance of methods to draw paths and shapes. These methods are all explained in [chapter 14 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=14). See for instance [paths.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter14/paths.pdf) and the code that was used to draw these paths, [PathConstructionAndPainting](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=241).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I wanted to draw a diagram on a new pdf, is there any way to center it?  I currently have the diagram positioned at 0,0 which is the bottom of the page.  Any way to move it to the top while starting the diagram at 0,0?

Comment: Draw the diagram on a `PdfTemplate` object. Then position the `PdfTemplate` where ever you want. Either by using the `addTemplate()` method in the `PdfContentByte` class, or by wrapping the `PdfTemplate` instance inside an `Image` object (it will remain a vector image).